# Improved UltraEdit wordfile for Ruby? (code folding)

Tags: ruby, code-folding, ultraedit

The default Ruby wordfile in UltraEdit does not support code folding.  Is there a Ruby wordfile for UltraEdit that does support code folding?

Comment: I've never tried it, but you might check if the one available for download from their website is any better (from http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/extras.html): http://www.ultraedit.com/files/wf/ruby.uew

Answer (score 0):

The help doc says if code folding is not specified for that extension, it'll default to braces. But that doesn't seem to be the case. I looked in the C/C++ word file and found

```
/Open Fold Strings = "{"
/Close Fold Strings = "}"
```

so if that's enough for you just add that to your word file. You can also use other tokens:

```
/Open Fold Strings = "{" "def" "if" "while" "class"
/Close Fold Strings = "}" "end" "end" "end" "end"
```

UE is pretty flexible - give it a go!

Comment: This runs into a problem when encountering a statement like print "hello" if friendly. If this is within nested loops or conditionals, the code folding breaks because of the lone 'if'.